# Force from right angle to the opposite side

Tags: vectors

> $ABC$ is a triangle, right angled at $A$. The resultant of the forces acting along $AB$, $AC$ with magnitudes $\frac1{AB}$ and $\frac1{AC}$ respectively is the force along $AD$, where $D$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $A$ onto $BC$. The magnitude of the resultant is
> (1)$\frac{{AB}^2+{AC}^2}{(AB)^2(AC)^2}$
> (2) $\frac{(AB)(AC)}{AB+AC}$
> (3) $\frac1{AB}+\frac1{AC}$
> (4) $\frac1{AD}?$

I understand that the forces given are $AB$ unit vector and $AC$ unit vector. So, by parallelogram law of vectors, $AD$ would be in the direction of $AB+AC$?

Also, by triangle law, I get that $BC=AC-AB$. And, $BC\cdot AD=0$. How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that it looks like the question is using AB to refer to the length of the segment AB of the triangle, and the same with AC.

If we label $\vec{i}$ as a unit vector along AB, and $\vec{j}$ as a unit vector along AC (where $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$ are perpendicular to each other),

then our resultant force is just

$\vec{f} = (\frac{1}{AB})\vec{i} + (\frac{1}{AC})\vec{j}$

We just use the pythagorean theorem to get the magnitude of the resultant

$|\vec{f}| = \sqrt{(\frac{1}{AB})^2+(\frac{1}{AC})^2}$

Now we can use a theorem from geometry

$\frac{1}{AB^2}+\frac{1}{AC^2} = \frac{1}{AD^2}$

This theorem is described in the altitudes section here:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle#:~:text=The%20Pythagorean%20theorem%20states%20that,meet%20at%20a%20right%20angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle#:%7E:text=The%20Pythagorean%20theorem%20states%20that,meet%20at%20a%20right%20angle)).

So we finally get

$|\vec{f}|=\frac{1}{AD}$

Comment: +1 good solution!

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks.